# Is there a way to get Packet Tracer to generate a label with device settings?

Tags: packet-tracer

In Packet Tracer I create my labels manually,

```
IP: 192.168.1.5
SM: 255.255.255.0
GW: 192.168.1.1
```

Is there a way to get Packet Tracer to generate a label like that, so I don't have to type it in for all my machines?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little be more in what exactly you mean with labels, maybe with a specific example. I have been using packet tracer for a long time but not sure what you mean.

Comment: @EduardoToro I was calling a note a label.  I think it is called a note, instead.  I can change it.

Comment: @johnny did the answer help you out? If so, you should accept it so that it doesn't keep popping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Packet tracer does not generate those label automatically. It displays most of these data when you move the cursor over the device, but it does not generate labels automatically.